# Parse Recursive pointers query

Tags: parse-platform

I'm currently trying to execute a query on a table, but I've got some problems with the pointers.

In the table, I have a pointer to a User. The User himself has a Pointer to a Object "Company".
When I do this, I get the user (username, etc), but not the company:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Infos");
query.whereEqualTo("status", 1);
query.include("user");
query.findInBackground(...);
```

How am I supposed to get the pointers inside of the pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational) (right at the end of that section, just before "Querying the Local Datastore), just use the dot syntax:

```
query.include("user.company");
```

Make sure you use the column names.

Then you can get the "user", and from that get the "company".